# MS SQL Query min/max/average per day

Tags: sql-server

I have a query:

```
WITH cte AS(
SELECT T3.DateTime AS AADateTime,
        (T3.In_Minbps/1000)/1000 AS MinReceiveMbps,
                (T3.In_Maxbps/1000)/1000 AS MaxReceiveMbps,
                (T3.In_Averagebps/1000)/1000 AS AvgReceiveMbps,
                (T3.Out_Minbps/1000)/1000 AS MinTransmitMbps,
                (T3.Out_Maxbps/1000)/1000 AS MaxTransmitMbps,
                (T3.Out_Averagebps/1000)/1000 AS AvgTransmitMbps
FROM dbo.Nodes AS T1
    INNER JOIN dbo.Interfaces AS T2 ON [T1].[NodeID] = [T2].[NodeID]
    INNER JOIN InterfaceTraffic AS T3 ON [T2].[InterfaceID] = [T3].[InterfaceID]
WHERE [T1].[Caption] = 'cust-firewall01' 
    AND [T2].[InterfaceName] = 'reth0' 
    AND DateTime >= '2014-08-01 00:00:00' AND DateTime <= '2014-08-31 23:59:59'
)
SELECT MIN(AADateTime) AS AADateTime,
        MIN(MinReceiveMbps) AS MinReceiveMbps,
        MAX(MaxReceiveMbps) AS MaxReceiveMbps,
        MIN(MinTransmitMbps) AS MinTransmitMbps,
        MAX(MaxTransmitMbps) AS MaxTransmitMbps,
        AVG(AvgTransmitMbps) AS AvgTransmitMbps,
        AVG(AvgReceiveMbps) AS AvgReceiveMbps
FROM cte
```

The above query works however returns an min/max/average of all records, what I need to do is return min/max/average per day. example table data is:

```
Date,                In_Minbps, In_Maxbps, In_Averagebps, Out_Minbps, Out_Maxbps, Out_Averagebps
2014-08-01 00:00:00, 403227.2, 3489988,    1986171,       6509198,    6.510824e+07, 33357.06
2014-08-01 01:00:00, 404039.1, 3626866,    2211984,       4491261,    6.61291e+07, 37061.19
```

there are basically 24 records per day I need this per day:

```
SELECT MIN(AADateTime) AS AADateTime,
        MIN(MinReceiveMbps) AS MinReceiveMbps,
        MAX(MaxReceiveMbps) AS MaxReceiveMbps,
        MIN(MinTransmitMbps) AS MinTransmitMbps,
        MAX(MaxTransmitMbps) AS MaxTransmitMbps,
        AVG(AvgTransmitMbps) AS AvgTransmitMbps,
        AVG(AvgReceiveMbps) AS AvgReceiveMbps
FROM cte
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CAST(Datetimefield AS DATE) AS Date,
        MIN(MinReceiveMbps) AS MinReceiveMbps,
        MAX(MaxReceiveMbps) AS MaxReceiveMbps,
        MIN(MinTransmitMbps) AS MinTransmitMbps,
        MAX(MaxTransmitMbps) AS MaxTransmitMbps,
        AVG(AvgTransmitMbps) AS AvgTransmitMbps,
        AVG(AvgReceiveMbps) AS AvgReceiveMbps
FROM cte
GROUP BY CAST(Datetimefield AS DATE)
```

Its group by date your records.